# How to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{h(x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)h(x)}{g(x)}}$?

Tags: calculus

How to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{h(x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{f(x)h(x)}{g(x)}}$ I have tried, l'hopital rule, decomposition of the limit similar to the $(1+1/f(x))^{f(x)}$ but got nothing.

I conjectured this but I am not sure it is true or not(my intuition says it is true)
How to show this is positively or negatively properly?

Answer (score 5):

This would be true if $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$
because, in this case,

$$\Bigl(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\Bigr)^{h(x)}=e^{h(x)\ln(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})}$$
and

$$\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\Bigr)\sim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
so
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(x)\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\Bigr)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}h(x)\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

If $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\ne 0$, it is not always true. you can check it with $ f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=1$.